# Selecting all rows related rows when row contains user

Tags: mysql, sql, typeorm

Let's say I have the following simple layout (this is a simplified version of what I have, in reality I'm using TypeORM to achieve this);

```
user(id, name)
game(id, name)
players(id, userId, gameId)
```

Now I would like to retrieve all `games` and `players` in which the user participated.

The following query would obtain all players in a game;

```
SELECT g.id, p.* FROM games g JOIN players p ON g.id = p.gameId
```

Now I however want to filter this by only selection all the `games` and `players` a specific user has participated in. What I did was the following;

```
SELECT g.id, p.* FROM games g JOIN players p ON g.id = p.gameId WHERE p.userId = :userId
```

Now this obviously returns all the rows of the player. But how could I also get the other players in which `:userId` participated? It seems like such an easy thing to do but I can't really wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try joining `players` table twice and `games` table once:

```
SET @userid := 1;

SELECT g.id, p1.*
FROM players p1
 JOIN players p2
   ON p1.gameId=p2.gameId
 JOIN games g 
   ON p1.gameId=g.id
WHERE p1.userId= @userId;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a92d5de73252b11c0fb7a15b523c0b07)